# calculating eigenvalue of an image

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, eigenvalue

I have some images and would like to look at the eigenvalues of the images (as image is a matrix). My issue is that the image is in the shape of `TensorShape([577, 700, 3])`

How can I possibly to some preprocessing to be able to have its eigen decomposition?

My try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg')
image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))

LA.eig(image)
```

Comment: What are eigenvalues of a non-square matrix?

Comment: Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are defined with respect to operator matrices. I'm afraid it doesn't make sense to calculate eigenvalues of an image matrix, which is just
a 2d array of pixel values. If you're interested in image compression algorithm,
please refer to sotething like KLT, Karhunen–Loève transform.

Answer (score 1):

A grayscale image can be (and usually is) represented as a matrix. A colored image can not. It is represented using three matrices, one for each color channel.

This is the problem with your code snippet. `la.eig()` expects a square array, or an array containing square arrays in its final two axes, but got an array of shape `(224, 224, 3)`.

To fix this, you can shift the two `224` axes to the end using the [`np.rollaxis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) function. The eigenvalues and -vectors will be calculated separately for each color channel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `n` images, and if images are of the same size, and if images are somehow centered, then you may consider that images are samples from a distribution, and you *can* use eigenvalue decomposition to study how different pixels in the image vary across the collection.

In this situation: say you have a collection of `n` `[H,W]` images. You can flatten images and form a `[H*W, n]` matrix. If the images are RGB, it can be a `[H*W*3, n]` array -- i.e. each pixel location and each color channel is treated as an independent dimension.

Eigenvalue decomposition will give you a collection of `H*W*3`-dimensional vectors, which can be reshaped back into RGB images. Getting *all* eigenvectors is going to be impossible (`H*W*3*H*W*3` is usually huge), however calculating top 3-5 eigenvalues and eigenvectors shouldn't be a problem even if `HxWx3` is large.

You can find a more detailed description searching for "Eigenfaces"; e.g. [opencv-eigenfaces-for-face-recognition](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/10/opencv-eigenfaces-for-face-recognition/), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface), [classic CVPR91 paper](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Emturk/Papers/mturk-CVPR91.pdf), etc.